# CloudFront + S3+ EC2 - domain name shows unsecure even though SSL certificate is installed

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

**Issue:**

1. When I access my website https://www.guidancecoding.com/ and try to login It shows unsecure, even though SSL certificate is present in the browser.

**Questions:**

1. Any thought as to why it is happening?
2. Any idea how to resolve it?
3. Does anyone need more information to better understand this problem.? There is too much information in the whole process and I am not sure what will add value. It will be great if you guys can feel free to ask me for relevant information.

**Description:**

1. website: https://www.guidancecoding.com/ .
2. I am trying to deploy(Angular+ springboot) application in s3 and Ec2 using elastic beanstalk.
3. S3 is where my Angular static content is present.
4. Ec2 along with a loadbalancer serves the spring-boot API.
5. CloudFront origin is S3.

Important notes:

1. An SSL certificate for guidancecoding.com and [www.guidancecoding.com](http://www.guidancecoding.com) is created and installed in loadbalancer using elastic bean stalk. (Mumbai region)
2. An SSL certificate for guidancecoding.com and [www.guidancecoding.com](http://www.guidancecoding.com) is created in N. Virginia for AWS CloudFront. (This is a requirement).

Project Architecture:

1. Domain Name (guidancecoding.com) points to cloudfront url.
2. Cloudfront points to Angular app in S3 bucket.
3. Once app is open in browser, the browser makes API request to elastic bean environment for data.

Image for reference:
[image]

Additional information from safari console.
[image]

Comment: I can see the SSL lock on your site, is it resolved?

Comment: No, It is not solved.I am moving out from this backend infrastructure. Note: The loading of website through cloudfront was successful (SSL cert was coming from N. Virginia) but when I tried to login, it need to talk to loadbalancer which has SSL cert  from mumbia region. And it is here that it shows "Not secure" message on url.